# Display array vertically using CSS - vertical-lr

Tags: css

Need your help in displaying this array vertically:

```css
.vericaltext {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='vericaltext'>{[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}</h1>
```

What it does is display the last index not the way I need:

I need the array to be displayed like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and not like this :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
0
```

Anyone got an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I am guessing the array is coming from javascript right and not like above in HTML?

Comment: `vertical-lr` is meant for displaying languages that are written top-to-bottom, nor for displaying languages written left-to-right vertically. If you're using React (previously the code had `className` instead of `class`, preventing the display of the CSS), you can do this by using `map`: `{[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(i => (<p>{i}</p>)}` (at a guess, I've not done React much).

Comment: You'll probably want to wrap each number in a `span` and use `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on the `h1`.

Comment: What is the actual HTML that is produced by whatever pre-processor you are using? (It isn't like the array you have shown in the code you have given).

Answer (score 0):

What about **pre** tag?

```
<pre style="text-align:right;width:50px">
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just using `flex` to align the elements vertically (each element is inside a span) and then inserting it into the `div`.

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('vericaltext')[0];
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(ele=>{
  const mySpan= document.createElement('span');
  const textNode = document.createTextNode(ele);
  mySpan.appendChild(textNode);
  myDiv.appendChild(mySpan);
});
```

```css
.vericaltext {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin-right: 6px;
  background-color: #EEE;
 
}
```

```html
<h1 class='vericaltext'></h1>
```